# Como crear un objeto en php

Tags: php

De una consulta a la base de datos, recorriendo con un foreach obtengo lo siguiente:

```
[
0[]
1[]
2[]
n[]
]
```

intente con un json_encode pero muestra es:

```
[{0},{1},{2},{n}]
```

Necesito crear lo siguiente:

```
["productos":{"producto1":{...}, "producto2":{...},"producto_n":{...}}]
```

Aquí un poco de código hasta ahora

```
$producto = ControladorProducto::ctrMostrarProducto($item,$valor);

for($i = 0; $i < count($producto); $i++){

$productospedido= json_decode($producto[$i]["productos"], true);

$productositem=array();

foreach ($productospedido as $key => $value) {

$respuestaProducto = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarProductos($itemProducto, $valorProducto);

$productositems= array("id" =>$respuestaProducto[0]["id"],"titulo"=> $nombreproducto, "precio"=>$respuestaProducto[0]["precio"]);

array_push($productositem, $productositems);

$productosjson= json_encode($productositem);
}

}
```

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Pretender crear una estructura con llaves tales como: `producto1, producto2, productoN` es muy pobre, muy limitado y desaprovechar los beneficios de JSON y de un modelo de datos bien estructurado. Lo lógico sería tener una estructura así: `"productos":{"id":1, "nombre":"producto1",...},{"id":2, "nombre":"producto2",...}, {"id":999, "nombre":"producto999",...}}`  Ahí estaríamos ante una estructura totalmente manejable y que puedes leer de forma indistinta, haya 1 producto o haya 999... productos. Si quieres el `id` o el `nombre` tienes una clave para ello.

Comment: me podrías dar un ejemplo de como realizar esa estructura?

Comment: Hola @mariamby, ¿aún tienes interés en esto? Es por pedirte el dataset de la base de datos a ver si viendo los datos consigo entender lo que necesitas... Saludos